# Collapse menus in mobile UX

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

This web app has 2 menus essentially, the one on the left hand side (3 items) and the the user profile menu also on the left (drop-down opens once you click on picture).

What would be the best way to display these on mobile? Hide both elements, move them around? Looking for the best practices for something like this. Thanks!

[image: Web app]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's a 'best way', here's one idea to get you started though.

[image]